# is it possible to use FTP in DOS operating system?

Tags: ftp, operating-systems

is there a possibility of networking in DOS6.22, and can I use FTP in DOS operating system?

Comment: Yes, networking is possible in DOS, although it has been so long ago, I couldn't tell you how to do it. I do know it requires extra software. As for FTP, I have not done that, but I bet it is possible too.

Comment: Is this really a "can I"  question? Seems like it's a bad fit for this Q and A site sadly :S

Comment: The answer of how to use networking in a DOS machine was given in your first question on this site. Given that all your questions revolve around DOS in a VM I'm going to assume that this is a continuation of that theme. Read the answer on your original question, and ask a question detailing your actual problems rather than asking open ended "is this even possible" type questions.

Comment: better to ask How than if it's possible.

Comment: Essentially the answer to your questions so far is just "yes, you can almost certainly do this." It would be better for you to detail what you have done, the problems you are having and where you are stuck. Specific questions are good, vague questions are bad.

Comment: @Mokubai  You write "The answer of how to use networking in a DOS machine was given in your first question on this site. " <-- well his first question was more about sharing folders.. not FTP.  Sharing folders doesn't tend to be what people mean by FTP so it is a different question. And just because it's the same theme doesn't mean he should squeeze it all into the same question

Comment: @barlop the FTP program is just that, *a program*. It requires nothing more than a *functional* network stack in order to work. An FTP *server* might require more programs, but OP has not given us enough information to find out which way he is going.  OP has already been given the answer to "is it possible to do networking in DOS" so it leaves us with a vague question about whether or not you can "do" FTP which is ambiguous at best. I can close this as "unclear" if you'd prefer, as in its current state that is where it stands. We need information before this is definitively answerable.

Comment: @Mokubai  The question he has asked here "is it possible" is poor and not very useful. I'm saying that throwing How Do You Do FTP into his first question(which is about sharing folders between a host and guest), would not be a good move.  A better form of this question would be How do you do FTP.. and he could mention things he has tried.  I notice that http://www.opus.co.tt/dave/internet.htm  mentions some tcp stack drivers (I don't know much about drivers or how software interacts with tcp stacks) i'm not sure if any FTP program would be compatible with any tcp stack driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: yes, it's possible, and an FTP client is part of the available toolset.

Basically, what you need is a network card and an MSDOS-oriented driver. On top of that you're going to need support of a network stack (such as TCP/IP) as well as a network-oriented userspace toolset (uncluding an FTP client). The details of how to set this up from scratch would be far beyond the scope of this question.

Source: Memory lane. I had two MSDOS computers in an IPX/SPX network around 20 years ago.